# ices2+icecast2 glitchy between songs

Tags: audio, streaming

For some reason clients are dropped / playing hangs between tracks.

As if server side doesn't use back2back/circular buffer, and just drops buffer content when changing song.

Anyone experienced this? Not sure if it's in ices2 or icecast2.
Can't get support for these open source projects.

Comment: do you start a new instance of `ices` for each "song"?

Comment: No, one ices2 fed by m3u list of 2 short songs, I experience the glitch even on local network. I tried ezsrteamer too with icecast2, same issue. 
So I think it's the icecast2. Same glitch with clients: Potplayer, VLC.

Comment: which version of icecast2? I use various icecast source programs (BUTT, ffmpeg, a couple I wrote myself) and icecast2 never glitches for me

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm using the latest Icecast 2.4.4,  have you tried with PotPlayer or VLC? On winamp it's a lot better but still not as perfect as commercial channels.

Comment: are you now talking about players or sources? I'm confused

Comment: sorry, I notice the glitch when I listen to icecast from clients PotPlayer or VLC, and less glitch on winamp, still on local LAN.

Comment: In fact if I go to Icecast2 Status page and start playing on web interface it still gets confused when songs end, still on LAN.

Comment: Oh, I don't use any such player, only a HTML Audio element. So, you're using ices 2, not ices 0? ... by the way, IceS doesn't do anything with m3u list, it reads standard input and sends it to icecast ...

Comment: yes, ices2 with opus, here I read that files need to have same encoding like CBR/VBR which I don't want to believe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63027707/icecast-i-have-strange-behaviour-with-repeats-of-end-of-tracks-as-well-as-pitc

Comment: I guess you're using the "Playlist" input module for ices?

Comment: yes ices2 playlist.xml, random 0, restart-after-reread 0, once 0

Comment: are all the files in the playlist the same encoding? Seems what you don't want to believe *may* be true (haven't looked at ices2 source to confirm though) since your playlist is 2 songs, have you tried re-encoding them so they do use the same encoding? that would be a good test

Comment: Both song encoded the same way with CBR opus, so I ran out of ideas, is there an alternative for icecast2 that pays opus?

Comment: Did you remove the `<encode>` section of the config for your playlist?

Comment: Yes, no encode section, to save CPU, config is as close to default as possible.
If you have a working icecast2 station could you send over the link so I could test it with VLC/Potplayer? To my long email:  cef5d6dd-129f-48f3-8070-fdb926966c8d@nsa82.anonaddy.com

Comment: see if adding an `<encode>` section helps - considering how OGG containers work, I think this may be the problem - my icecast is live only, and I only use it if for some reason my self written system stops working, which is rare